# glsl sqrt result is negative

Tags: glsl, sqrt

I have a blur function in my shader which takes a float as the blur radius.

I calculate the distance from the center of the screen like this:

```
vec2 nPos = texCoord.xy - vec2(0.5, 0.5);
float d = sqrt(nPos.x * nPos.x + nPos.y * nPos.y)/sqrt2; //ranged from 0 to 1
```

Now I call my blur function like this:

`gl_FragColor = chromaticBlur(pr, pg, pb, d, size);`

The weird thing is, if I set d to 0, there is no blur, just as expected (values above 0 work as expected too). But if I use the function shown above, a huge part of the screen (in fact an oval) will be black. That means that the blur value for this area is negative, which SHOULD be impossible. How can that happen?

Comment: could you bring your shader on http://glsl.heroku.com/ for testing? and post your link here.

Comment: It doesn't compile on there. I don't seem to be able to see the error message too. Also it requires a texture to be visible.

Comment: nevermind, I just found out that my blur fails between 0 and 0.6 for some reason

Comment: Huge part of the screen turning black could be a NaN too; perhaps from a divide by zero or sqrt of negative number?